# R and Shiny: Pass inputs from sliders to reactive function to compute output

Tags: r, function, output, shiny

I have 6 parameters that the user can change values for. These are our 6 inputs. 
I want to create an output value that takes those 6 inputs and computes our value of interest given a number of related equations in a function. Here is what I have in my UI...

```
library(shiny)

# Define UI for slider demo application
shinyUI(pageWithSidebar(

#  Application title
headerPanel("# Header Title Goes Here"),

# Sidebar with sliders that demonstrate various available options
sidebarPanel(
# Simple integer interval
sliderInput("u1", "Name:", 
            min=0, max=10000, value=10000),
#There are 6 slider inputs...

    ),

# Show a table summarizing the values entered
mainPanel(
 tableOutput("values"),

 uiOutput("focal"))
 )
)
```

Here is what I have in my server.R...

```
library(shiny)

shinyServer(function(input, output) {

# Reactive expression to compose a data frame containing all of the values
sliderValues <- reactive({

# Compose data frame
data.frame(
  Name = # Names of my 6 parameters,

  Value = # inputs based on my 6 values by `input$value`,

  stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
})

f <- renderText({function(r1, r2, r3, d1, d2, u1) #these are my 6 values
{ #List of equations that compute f based on the 6 values
}
})


# Show the values using an HTML table
output$values <- renderTable({
sliderValues()
})

# Show the final calculated value 
output$focal <- renderText({
f
})
})
```

I keep getting... Error: argument 1(type 'closure') cannot be handled by 'cat'
and many other errors. I just don't how to transfer the updated user inputs of the 6 parameters to my function and spit that function back out in the output area on the Shiny html page.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!!

Thanks!

Comment: ReactiveUI is a Different Thing™

Comment: why is that a trademarked phrase?

Answer (score 25):

I think there are a couple of confusions here. Firstly, where you define `f` in `server.R`, I think you just want to define a function the way you normally would. Then, when you do `renderText()`, you can call the function to get your value.

The way you have it now, you're creating a function inside `renderText()`, which you're then trying to get `renderText` to display, without giving it your arguments. That's why you're getting the error message, because `renderText` passes its first argument to `cat`, which does not know what to do with the function. It can, however, handle the *output* of a function.

Anyway, the following works for me. I've only done two sliders, but you can presumably extend it yourself.

ui.R:

```
#ui.R
library(shiny)

# Define UI for slider demo application
shinyUI(pageWithSidebar(

  #  Application title
  headerPanel("# Header Title Goes Here"),

  # Sidebar with sliders that demonstrate various available options
  sidebarPanel(
    # Simple integer interval
    sliderInput("u1", "Name:", 
                min=0, max=10000, value=10000),
    sliderInput("r1", "r1:", 
                min=0, max=10000, value=10000)


  ),

  # Show a table summarizing the values entered
  mainPanel(
    tableOutput("values"),

    uiOutput("focal"))
)
)
```

server.R

```
#server.R
library(shiny)

shinyServer(function(input, output) {

  # Reactive expression to compose a data frame containing all of the values
  sliderValues <- reactive({

    # Compose data frame
    data.frame(
      Name = c("u1", "r1"),

        Value = c(input$u1,
                  input$r1),

        stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
  })

  f <- function(u1, r1) {
    u1 + r1
  }


  # Show the values using an HTML table
  output$values <- renderTable({
    sliderValues()
  })

  # Show the final calculated value 
  output$focal <- renderText(
    {f(input$u1, input$r1)}
  )
})
```

Comment: HOLY COW!! THIS TOTALLY WORKS!! THANK YOU SO MUCH!!! I WORKED ON THIS ALL DAY!!! MANY THANKS TO YOU!!!!! HAVE A BEAUTIFUL DAY!